# TinyMCE (or JCE) - How to get current node name and html content

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to check at which node the cursor / selection is.

I want to get the

- node name
- html inside the node

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The node can be accessed using:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode()
```

And there are 2 properties that will return the wanted values: *nodeName* and *innerHTML*

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().nodeName

tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().innerHTML
```